# Python IOError.strerror is not Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, ioerror

When a non-latin locale is set, `IOError.strerror` becomes non-Unicode in Python 2.7 for me:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print locale.getlocale(locale.LC_MESSAGES)

try:
    open('/asdasd', 'w')
except IOError as e:
    print e.strerror
    print repr(e.strerror)
    print unicode(e) # boom
```

Running:

```
LANG=fr_FR.utf8 python test.py
```

Output:

```
('fr_FR', 'UTF-8')
Permission non accordée
'Permission non accord\xc3\xa9e'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print unicode(e)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It looks like OS error messages are stored in `strerror` as-is, without converting to Unicode first.
Can this be worked around without manually decoding every `Exception`?

Comment: e is a exception object. How you think to unicode it?

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly. I'm talking about ``e.strerror`` attribute.

Comment: @Denis if you are talking about ``unicode(e)`` part, this should return a string representation of the object, much like ``str(e)``

Comment: I don't thinck so when you print some object it's just like call __str__ method of this object but for example if you print type of object you get result like this <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>

Comment: @Denis, print calls ``repr`` for objects, but this is not what the question is about.

Comment: print unicode(e) your error and exception is raised when your pass exception object in unicode function

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is going to be much of an answer, but:

Python 2 has some places (exceptions being one of them) where the nice distinction between "text" and "bytes" isn't made cleanly. In practice, in **Python 2**, every string in an exception I've ever seen is a `str`, or `bytes`. (Not that a custom library couldn't return `unicode`, but the standard Python stuff doesn't.) Thus, you see the system's error as a `str`/`bytes`. You can make this work by changing the last line (the `# boom`) to:

```
print unicode(str(e), 'utf-8')
```

or, as I prefer,

```
print str(e).decode('utf-8')
```

Now, that `'utf-8'` is a magic constant here: it must match the locale (which, for `fr_FR.utf8`, it does. For other, non UTF-8 locales, it might not.) `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, I believe, will give you the correct answer, thus:

```
print str(e).decode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

There is light at the end of the tunnel: In **Python 3**, the code you posted should¹ Just Work. (With the minor typical Py3k alterations — `print()` is a functions, and `unicode` needs to be `str`.)

¹I can get it to work with fr_FR.utf-8, but not fr_FR.ISO-8859-1. No idea why. The latter encoding works with Python 2. Python 3 runs with the modifications I mentioned, but appears to just drop the accent entirely.

Comment: This indeed works, but take a look at my answer (I have figured out a way to enforce UTF-8 in exception strings).

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured it out:

By default, Python 2 uses `ascii` as system encoding (see `sys.getdefaultencoding`).

Unfortunately there's no `setdefaultencoding` (more precisely, it's getting deleted from `sys` module by `site.py`), so the solution I used is following:

```
import locale
import sys

reload(sys)  # reload sys so sys.setdefaultencoding is available again
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

try:
    open('/asdasd', 'w')
except IOError as e:
    print unicode(e)
```

Comment: Should not do this, as the code will likely not work on other systems:  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-February/598689.html

Comment: http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/changing-the-python-default-encoding-considered-harmful.html